# How can I hard-code a URL with translations in a template?

Tags: 8

I already followed [Get node alias in template](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/205683/get-node-alias-in-template).

In the template file I have this code.

```
<a href="/about-us" title="{{ 'About Us'|t }}">{{ 'About Us'|t }}</a>
```

I am using multiple languages, so it should work fine with /th/about-us.

I want to achieve it directly in the template file. How can I do it?

Comment: have you tried any of the solutions here https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/205683/get-node-alias-in-template ?

Comment: Yes but don't want to give via URL Alias or Node Id. Because it will be changed in Local & Live version. So can't use that

Comment: You want to hard-code an URL into the template and additionally provide multi-language support? - A really bad idea. What if the page URL will be called "/about-us" in English and "/เกี่ยวกับเรา" in Thai? You never know, what content editors do. ;) - Better provide a theme, site or module setting to define the node ID of the about us page, or - which I'd suggest for generic links as "about us" - a separate translatable menu / menu block.

Comment: @Mike: If you offer more details where you want to use the link (what kind of template?/is it visible on all pages?/are there other links as well, or only the 'about us' link?), I might be able to specifying one of the above mentioned alternative solutions to your hard-coding.

Comment: I agree and vote to close this as duplicate, because the question says it did follow the linked topic, but the code doesn't show it. And without more details it's not possible to provide a different answer.