# How to print the URL path of a referenced node using paragraphs?

Tags: 8, theming, paragraphs

I'm trying to print out the url path of a node from a referenced entity paragraph field in my twig template however have not had any success so far. I have tried various common twig functions but with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can simply use the reference field's formatter under display settings to display a link, no? Directly in Twig you can get the referenced node's ID and the use it to create the URL like shown here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/255882/15055

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get node alias in template](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/205683/get-node-alias-in-template)

Answer (score 4):

Use the Twig path() function and build a node route with the target id of the reference field:

*paragraph.html.twig*

```
{% if paragraph.field_example.target_id %}
  <a href="{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': paragraph.field_example.target_id}) }}">{{ 'View node page'|t }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

See https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/functions-in-twig-templates